# Doxygen: Documenting single API that has multiple implementations

Tags: comments, doxygen

Suppose I have one header file with a couple of functions and multiple source files that implement the functions that the header provided.
I would like to document the functions using Doxygen, but only the general comments regarding all implementations, not implementation specific.

What is the best way to see only the header comments? I can't set configuration to ignore all source files as some other source files in the projects don't have headers at all.

For example:

**api.h**

```
/**
*  @details
*   This is general comment for header
*
*********************************************************************/
```

**implemenation1.c**

```
/**
*  @details
*   This is implementation specific comment for file 1
*
*********************************************************************/
int foo(int a, int b)
{
  ...
}
```

**implemenation2.c**

```
/**
*  @details
*   This is implementation specific comment for file 2
*
*********************************************************************/
int foo(int a, int b)
{
  ...
}
```

I want to see only that comment on Doxygen:

```
This is general comment for header
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe have a look at \cond and \if constructs ?

Comment: yeah, that solves it, even though I was hoping to have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solultion I've found so far is this:

**api.h**

```
/**
*  @details
*   This is general comment for header
*
*********************************************************************/
```

**implemenation1.c**

```
/**
*  @details
*   This is implementation specific comment for file 1
*
*  @cond
*********************************************************************/

int foo(int a, int b)
{
  ...
}

/** @endcond */
```

**implemenation2.c**

```
/**
*  @details
*   This is implementation specific comment for file 2
*
*  @cond
*********************************************************************/

int foo(int a, int b)
{
  ...
}

/** @endcond */
```

Comment: I would even move the cond into the documentation block.

Comment: Done. Thanks! :)

Comment: I meant even above the details, just check the results as well.